# Issue configuring iTunes

Tags: itunes

After a re-install of Windows 10 I also re-installed iTunes (v12.7.1). I have my music in a folder of my own, so I went to Edit -> Preferences -> Advanced, and changed the iTunes Media folder location, expecting to see my dozen or so playlists.

[image]

Unfortunately they aren't displayed.

As far as I know playlist data is stored in

> iTunes library.itl

which by default is in

> C:\users\joris\Music\iTunes\

The default media folder location is (oddly) one level down, at

> C:\users\joris\Music\iTunes\iTunes Media\

So, as my *iTunes library.itl* is in

> D:\Libraries\Music\iTunes\

I figured I'd have to set the media folder location to

> D:\Libraries\Music\iTunes\iTunes Media\

This doesn't work. How can I fix this?

Comment: Try going to iTunes > Preferences > Advanced, and check "Share iTunes Library XML with other applications". This *should* generate an XML file containing all your playlists from the Library.itl file, but it may not be successful due to iTunes not currently identifying your playlists. If it does create an XML file try opening it and using "CTRL + F" to find the name of one of your playlists. If you're lucky, that might mean an easy solution

Comment: Try File > Library > "Consolidate files". Try also [this method](https://discussions.apple.com/message/15969190#message15969190).